# deceptively simple bevel issue

Tags: modeling

I made a flap for a backpack a few months ago. I cannot for the life of me figure out how I did it. I did an extrude to create the raised perimeter and increased it's scale which explains the elongated mesh near the perimeter. I used a simple deform bend to accomplish the bend. I just can't figure out how I beveled the corners with such clean uniform subdivision on the mesh. I think I did a face insert to define the perimeter, so starting from a single face it's gotta be some combination of face insert, subdivide, bevel and solidify(or extrude) but no matter what I try I can't replicate this. pls halp

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

best I could do was starting from a single face -> extrude -> percent bevel -> proportional scale down (to increase perimeter width) -> loop subdivide x2. But as you can see it's just not the same[image]